# GORM criteria query filtering where id in list

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I'm trying to add a clause to an existing GORM criteria to do some extra filtering.

I have various objects in my domain that are owned by an `Organisation`. For example, `Product`. Organisations can also own other organisations. I only want `User`s who belong to a particular `Organisation` to be able to see domain objects that belong to that `Organisation` or any of their `Organisation`'s child `Organisation`s.

There are a number of places in my application where I need to query for domain objects that are owned by `Organisation`s. I want to create a `DetachedCriteria` instance that I can reuse throughout by application wherever I need to filter out objects that a `User` should not be allowed to see.

I've denormalised my model a bit to hopefully make things easier. When a new `Organisation` is inserted, it recursively adds itself to the `hierarchyOrganisations` collection of each of the `Organisations` above it.

```
class Organisation {
    ...
    static hasMany = [hierarchyOrganisations: Organisation]
    ...
}
```

One of the places I want to apply the organisation filtering `DetachedCriteria` is in Grails' scaffolding controller's `list` method, so I need to be able to paginate the final set of results.

Using the `Product` controller's list method as an example, I'm currently doing something like this -

```
def hierarchyCriteria = new DetachedCriteria(Organisation).build {
    eq('id', currentUserOrganisation.id)
}

def productInstanceList = Product.createCriteria().list {
    inList('parentOrganisation.id', hierarchyCriteria.list().each { organisation -> 
        organisation.hierarchyOrganisations.collect { it.id }
    })
}
```

...which works, but I don't think it will scale. I'll be hitting the database to bring back the collection of `hierarchyOrganisations`, then iterating over them in the application to pull out the id, and then querying again to bring back the final filtered list of organisations.

If I was using SQL, I could use a join or an inner select, but I can't seem to get the syntax right translating this to the GORM criteria dsl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using some SQL to augment the criteria.

By adding a `sqlRestriction` block to my criteria dsl I was able to add a subselect to apply the filtering I needed

I'd still be interested in finding out if this is possible using just the grails hibernate criteria dsl.

Answer (score 2):

```
def organisationInstanceList = Organisation.createCriteria().list {
    idEq(currentUserOrganisation.id)
    hierarchyOrganisations{
      //Eagerly fetch all children for the parent org
    }
}

def children = organisationInstanceList?.first().hierarchyOrganisations
```

I may be over-simplifying things, but the above should give you the `parent` org and the corresponding `children` orgs. What else do you need?

Adding to @Sergio's option:

The denormalization may be unnecessary. Data model can be used as

```
class Organisation {
    Organization parent
}
```

When a new organization is added, just map it to the corresponding parent, automatically an hierarchy is created.

In order to get, all the children(paginated) from a parent, use

```
def children = Organization.findAllByParent(currentUserOrganisation, [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```

Comment: Maybe he want the childrens and need to paginate them?

Comment: Added that option (an easier one indeed) as well @SérgioMichels. :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Rereading my question, I realised that I didn't really state my requirement very clearly - it's not just the hierarchy organisations that I need to query for, I need to be able to query for any object in my domain and apply the 'organisation filter' to make sure each domain object my query returns belongs to one of the organisations in my hierarchy or organisations. I've reworded the question a bit, and used a different object from my domain as an example of something I need to apply the filter to.